# How I can set the audio play when open this screen in react native

Tags: react-native

[image]

Hope any one can help me
Thank you so much .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [React-native-sound](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sound) to do it.

Example:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    this.sound = new Sound(this.props.urlAudio, null, error => {
      console.log("Audio loaded...")
      if (!error) {
          console.log("Audio starting...")
          this._startAudio()
      }
    })
}

_startAudio() {
   this.sound.play(()=> {
       console.log("Audio playing....")
   })
}
```

Comment: Thank yo for your ans . 
yes I'm try use this one but not auto play when open  the screen .

Comment: I've edited the answers, you can take a look